# Get Div from external file php

Tags: php

I am trying to get info from div class from an external link
how can I do that?

```
<div class="item-list"><h3>répartitions des gains</h3><ul id="partages" class="partages-gain"><li class="partage_header first"><div class="part_label">Combinez :</div><div class="num_gain">Nombre de gains</div><div class="lots">Lot (Rs)</div></li>
<li class="partage_number"><div class="part_label">6 des 6</div><div class="num_gain">0</div><div class="lots">0</div></li>
<li class="partage_number"><div class="part_label">5 des 6</div><div class="num_gain">59</div><div class="lots">11 776</div></li>
<li class="partage_number"><div class="part_label">4 des 6</div><div class="num_gain">3 093</div><div class="lots">463</div></li>
<li class="partage_number"><div class="part_label">3 des 6</div><div class="num_gain">48 021</div><div class="lots">100</div></li>
<li class="partage_total last"><div class="part_label">Total</div><div class="num_gain">51 173</div><div class="lots">6 928 943</div></li>
</ul></div>  </div>
```

Above is the the external link source code
am trying to get for example in `num_gain` which is `0` but there is `5` `num_gain` class and store it into a variable and then send it to my database.

Comment: What info do you want to retrieve?

Comment: Consider using http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php to work with html docs from external sites.

Comment: Use a dom parser. See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXpath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to do this i wrote this function for getting content from class name which returns an array

```
function getContentByClassName($html, $classname) {
     $content = array();
     $dom = new DomDocument();
     @$dom->loadHTML($html);
     $finder = new DomXPath($dom);

     $nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");

     foreach($nodes as $node){
        $content[] = $node->nodeValue;
     }
     return $content;
}
```

Usage

```
$html = file_get_contents('your external link');
$class = 'num_gain';
var_dump(getContentByClassName($html, $class));
```

Output

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 'Nombre de gains' 
  1 => '0' 
  2 => '59'
  3 => '3 093'
  4 => '48 021'
  5 => '51 173'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if your question asks about extracting one numeric value or multiple ones with respect to div tags of classname "num_gain". So, I offer an answer for each possibility, as follows:

If you wish to extract the zero in a "num_gain" div tag, I suggest this code:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/page_with_divs.html");
preg_match("/class=\"num_gain\">([0-9])<\//",$html,$matches);
$result = $matches[1]; // 0
```

Note, the variable assignment is optional. I favor it mainly for the sake of code legibility.

The code uses *preg_match()* with a regex.  The regex pattern excludes a match with the first num_gain DIV because it contains non-numeric data, namely "Nombre de gains". The pattern does match the next specified DIV tag since its text consists of of one digit, namely a zero.

If you do a  var_dump() of `$matches`, it produces the following results:

```
  array (size=2)
    0 => string 'class="num_gain">0</' (length=20)
    1 => string '0' (length=1)
```

The zeroth element contains the string that matched the regex pattern exactly while the next element contains the part of the pattern that was "remembered" with the aid of the parentheses.  Therefore, `$matches[1]` contains the desired value to store in the database.

If your question actually pertains to accessing the numeric data in num_gain class DIV tags, then you could write the following code which makes use of *preg_match_all()*:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/page_with_divs.html");
preg_match_all("/class=\"num_gain\">([0-9][0-9 ]*)<\//",$html,$matches);
```

`matches[1]` now contains the following array:

```
array (
  0 => '0',
  1 => '59',
  2 => '3 093',
  3 => '48 021',
  4 => '51 173',
)
```

A word of caution, while web scraping is technically easy to do, you should be sure that  this activity is legally permissible.